# how to read output of system('ls')?

Tags: c, linux

I am doing some file IO with c code. I have a particular pattern in my file. I can verify this by a shell command `cat abc.txt | grep abc | wc -l`. When I execute the same command using `System()`, it give proper output, but I have no clue how can I get its output into a variable and compare it in my c code itself.

I tried looking into man pages which suggest using `WEXITSTATUS()`. This actually returns the status of execution and not output.

F1 !!

Comment: Note, don't parse the output of `ls`.  And be aware that there are better options for file IO than shell calls via `system()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want `system(3)` for that. Try `popen(3)` and friends.

Comment: +1 here is an example of this http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/23/Popen.html

Comment: dont they have the same problem, calling the shell ?

Comment: @Tom i would have thought that the only major problem is if the program requested for execution is not in the $PATH of the calling process

Comment: My background is more on Windows. Is there any quick start book on Linux programming?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Linux-Application-Development-Michael-Johnson/dp/0201308215

Comment: He doesn't want either. Parsing the output of `ls` is a horrible idea. He wants `opendir` and `readdir` and `qsort`.

Comment: well the original command I wanted was 'cat abc.txt | grep abc | wc -l'. I just happen to put ls in title, just to make it short :)

Answer (score 1):

What grep and wc are doing are reading the STDIN file handle as part of the pipe |  operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
...
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){
    int fd = open("output", O_RDWR | O_CREATE);
    close(1);
    (void) dup(fd);  // this will return 1
    system(your_cmd);
    // read output from fd
    // close fd
    // exit
}
else{
...
```

This will redirect output from command executed by system() to your "output" file.